# tshark: http transaction info for specific outgoing port

Tags: linux, node.js, http, pcap, tshark

I am trying to debug an ETIMEDOUT issue in node when trying to talk to another service. 
my setup is 
1 server running node application which uses module dockerode to do inspect on container.
1 server running docker.

stack:

`Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)`

I want to figure out why this is happening. I read up a bit on tshark and it seems to have the data I want.

I am currently using this: `sudo tshark -i eth0` to get my information. example output:

`17   0.005451    10.0.1.10 -> 10.0.1.219   TCP 66 58321 > 4242 [ACK] Seq=146 Ack=2121 Win=31232 Len=0 TSval=431658268 TSecr=799817403
 18   0.006179    10.0.1.10 -> 10.0.1.219   TCP 66 58321 > 4242 [FIN, ACK] Seq=146 Ack=2121 Win=31232 Len=0 TSval=431658268 TSecr=799817403
 19   0.006228   10.0.1.219 -> 10.0.1.10    TCP 66 4242 > 58321 [FIN, ACK] Seq=2121 Ack=147 Win=28032 Len=0 TSval=799817403 TSecr=431658268
 20   0.006406    10.0.1.10 -> 10.0.1.219   TCP 66 58321 > 4242 [ACK] Seq=147 Ack=2122 Win=31232 Len=0 TSval=431658268 TSecr=799817403
 21   0.077692    10.0.1.10 -> 10.0.1.219   TCP 74 58326 > 4242 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=26883 Len=0 MSS=8961 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=431658286 TSecr=0 WS=128
21  22   0.077710   10.0.1.219 -> 10.0.1.10    TCP 74 4242 > 58326 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=26847 Len=0 MSS=8961 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=799817421 TSecr=431658286 WS=128
 23   0.077927    10.0.1.10 -> 10.0.1.219   TCP 66 58326 > 4242 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=27008 Len=0 TSval=431658286 TSecr=799817421
 24   0.078240    10.0.1.10 -> 10.0.1.219   HTTP 211 GET /containers/fbc1d9a897d46691c402daf34b35c017bcbcc04332dba603a71093e50cc61341/json HTTP/1.1
 25   0.078253   10.0.1.219 -> 10.0.1.10    TCP 66 4242 > 58326 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=146 Win=28032 Len=0 TSval=799817421 TSecr=431658286
 26   0.078824   10.0.1.219 -> 10.0.1.10    HTTP 2184 HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (application/json)
 27   0.079043    10.0.1.10 -> 10.0.1.219   TCP 66 58326 > 4242 [ACK] Seq=146 Ack=2119 Win=31232 Len=0 TSval=431658286 TSecr=799817421
 28   0.079831    10.0.1.10 -> 10.0.1.219   TCP 66 58326 > 4242 [FIN, ACK] Seq=146 Ack=2119 Win=31232 Len=0 TSval=431658286 TSecr=799817421
 29   0.079880   10.0.1.219 -> 10.0.1.10    TCP 66 4242 > 58326 [FIN, ACK] Seq=2119 Ack=147 Win=28032 Len=0 TSval=799817422 TSecr=431658286
 30   0.080129    10.0.1.10 -> 10.0.1.219   TCP 66 58326 > 4242 [ACK] Seq=147 Ack=2120 Win=31232 Len=0 TSval=431658287 TSecr=799817422
 31   0.084797    10.0.1.10 -> 10.0.1.219   TCP 74 58328 > 4242 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=26883 Len=0 MSS=8961 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=431658288 TSecr=0 WS=128
 32   0.084813   10.0.1.219 -> 10.0.1.10    TCP 74 4242 > 58328 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=26847 Len=0 MSS=8961 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=799817423 TSecr=431658288 WS=128
 33   0.084998    10.0.1.10 -> 10.0.1.219   TCP 66 58328 > 4242 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=27008 Len=0 TSval=431658288 TSecr=799817423
 34   0.085061    10.0.1.10 -> 10.0.1.219   HTTP 211 GET /containers/3b3714d4226c2307122ec5521e0241ad2f7a62f34b0e0fc0e08ae6213287621b/json HTTP/1.1
 35   0.085070   10.0.1.219 -> 10.0.1.10    TCP 66 4242 > 58328 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=146 Win=28032 Len=0 TSval=799817423 TSecr=431658288
 36   0.085618   10.0.1.219 -> 10.0.1.10    HTTP 2184 HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (application/json)`

I want to be able to tell what calls are associated with HTTP get request.

information I know:
the server we send request to = 10.0.1.10 on port 4242
HTTP url is /container/xxx/json
when error happens I know the URL which caused ETIMEDOUT

any help on how to associate the calls related to the HTTP call so I can figure out where things went wrong? Thanks in advance!

system info in case you need it:
`$ uname -a
Linux host 3.13.0-29-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 4 21:00:20 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out how to do this, adding  `-z proto,colinfo,tcp.stream,tcp.stream -w dump`
give a number you can used to map the entire transaction from handshake to close